# How can I make Perl's Getopt::Long not process a literal = in a parameter name?

Tags: perl, getopt-long

I wrote a Perl program "transfer.pl" and the input parameter is the hash value (the key and the value are strings). The code segment is:

```
my %transfers = ();

if (!GetOptions("transfer=s" => \%transfers))
{
    Usage();
    exit(1);
}
```

I used the windows system. On the command line, I typed:

> perl tranfer.pl --transfer "table = %s"="[TableName=%s]"

I hope the key is `table = %s` and the value is `[TableName=%s]`, but it seems Getopt::Long always finds the first `=` so the key is `table` and the value is `%s=[TableName=%s]`.

When I typed

> perl tranfer.pl --transfer "table \= %s"="[TableName\=%s]"

The key is `table \`, the value is `%s=[TableName\=%s]`.

I want to know how to bypass the "=" in my string value and make the code do what I expect?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

[`Getopt::Long`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Getopt::Long) will not allow this; the first `=` is always used to separate the key from the value.  You will need to use a [user-defined subroutine](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Getopt-Long/lib/Getopt/Long.pm#User-defined_subroutines_to_handle_options) to handle the option, or split up the `key=value` pairs after `GetOptions` is done or use some arbitrary escaping mechanism like using "`%25`" to represent a `=` in a key.

Answer (score 1):

From [`Getopt::Long`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Getopt::Long)

> If the option destination is a reference to a hash, the option will take, as value, strings of the form key=value. The value will be stored with the specified key in the hash.
>
> ```
> GetOptions ("define=s" => \%defines);
> ```
>
> Alternatively you can use:
>
> ```
> GetOptions ("define=s%" => \$defines);
> ```
>
> When used with command line options:
>
> ```
> --define os=linux --define vendor=redhat
> ```

It will always split on the first "`=`".